# Jump Through Polygon/Floor Collision Detection

Tags: python, collision-detection, pygame

I am trying to implement a Mario type plat-former in pyGame.  I have Collision detection working with Polygons no problem.  I am curious how I can get the player to be able to jump through the floor above him, which is a polygon floating in air.

What is the theory on how to handle that?

Comment: Probably as a sprite/block property, and in your collision detection it would be checked explicitly- if the player has a positive Y-speed and collides with a "jump-through" object, ignore this collision. It's probably quicker to handle like this than it is to partition the set of blocks into jump-through-able and non-jump-through-able.

Comment: To expand on jozzas comment: continue ignoring any collisions between the two objects until they are no longer colliding.

Comment: @Darthfett, continue to ignore is the piece of information in my head that I was missing.  I think this will help.

Answer (score 1):

you could make it so that when your character hits a block, they move up at the current speed until they are no longer colliding with the polygon. That way, when you hit the ground from above,you don't go downward through it, but when you hit the bottom, you do. I would recommend a while loop set to the collide function.